# How to make the size(B,1) = size(A,1)?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to Write a function that takes a matrix A as an input and returns the matrix B as the output. **B has the same number of rows as A.**

1. Each element of the first column of B contains the mean of the corresponding row of A.
2. The second column contains the median values.
3. While the third column has the minimums.
4. Each element of the fourth column of B is equal to the maximum value of given row of A.

```
function B = simple_stats (A)
n = size(A,1);
x = A(1,:);
y = median(A);
z = min(A);
r = max(A);
B = [x.',y.',z.',r.'];
B(1:n,:); % Here I have a problem and B has not the same number of rows as A.
end
```

Comment: you don't seem to have any iteration going on here. You're currently taking the max of the entire matrix, I think.

Comment: @OwenHempel: No iteration required here, MATLAB uses vectorisation.

Comment: @AJ Junior: Read the documentation for `mean`, especially for the `dim` parameter. You are calculating the mean of each column, not the mean of each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that you want to compute the `median`, `mean`, `min` and `max` across the *second* dimension of your matrix `A`. By default, all of these functions operate along the *first* dimension (down the columns). All of these functions take a `dim` parameter which is used to specify the dimension along which to apply the operation.

```
A = randi(10, 5, 3);

%// 8     3     3
%// 8     2     1
%// 6     3     5
%// 2     9     1
%// 6     1     9

B = [mean(A, 2), median(A, 2), min(A, [], 2), max(A, [], 2)];

%// 4.6667    3.0000    3.0000    8.0000
%// 3.6667    2.0000    1.0000    8.0000
%// 4.6667    5.0000    3.0000    6.0000
%// 4.0000    2.0000    1.0000    9.0000
%// 5.3333    6.0000    1.0000    9.0000
```